# Reduce app size cocs2d iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am new with cocs2d. I have created an app using Cocos2d. The app is working fine but problem is that application size is too large 350MB. There are many images in this app. I have used png and where possible jpeg images. There are many png images that have larger than 1 mb.

Is there any way to reduce the application size. I've reduced the size whereever possible. Is there any other format that can be used in place of png? There are no many animations. The png are used only purpose of transparency.

Comment: If you receive a correct answer, you should mark it as the correct one.
This will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Your images are way out of size. Even if you put them on server, and then download it will take time to download.

The best option is to reduce the image size. A couple of sites that can help you do that are:-

[Reduce image size](http://www.reduceimages.com/)

[Compress image size](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_reduce_the_file_size_of_a_PNG_file)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the image content on your server and then download the image content asynchronously (which is more imp download it first). If there are levels then download initial levels first and download remaining on the background thread. You can always display a loader on launch and display some help kinda stuff meanwhile the data gets download and cached.

You can make use of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and other libraries to get your images stuff async.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

While your pictures are fairly large and you should try to reduce the number and size, you can make gains through packaging the .png into pvr.ccz files. There are multiple different programs available to do this. I like to use Texture Packer which is available here: http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

Comment: I have created .png to pvr.ccz using TexturePacker b ut instead of reduce size it increased. Original png size was 534KB and generated pvr.ccz was 600KB.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some tips in my post on [reducing memory usage & bundle size](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/).

Most importantly use texture atlases in .pvr.ccz format and where possible reduce image color depth to 16 bit. Avoid JPGs altogether because they're terribly slow to load in cocos2d.

Comment: I have created .png to pvr.ccz using TexturePacker b ut instead of reduce size it increased. Original png size was 534KB and generated pvr.ccz was 600KB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in using png files although your images are too large, You can reduce their size by 70 - 80% by using tinypng and it will not going to hurt your graphics.

- https://tinypng.com/

Answer (score -1):

I usually edit the image size now https://resizeimage.io , you try!

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer.